# Image link not working with overlayed div when z-index is higher

Tags: css, hyperlink, position, z-index, supersized

I'm using supersized slideshow on a site but I have added a texture overlay in a div

```
 #slideshow-wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(/slideshow/img/slideshow-front-3.png) repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

this is the supersized div

```
 #supersized
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If I change the z-index on #slideshow-wrapper to 0 the link works great however I loose the texture over the image.

Is there a workaround for this so the link can work while still displaying the textured overlay?

Appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put an event listener on the texture image and capture the mouse coordinates, then pass along the click event to the item below it which *should have been* clicked, which shares the same coordinate space.

Comment: Will this work for several images/links that rotate underneath the #slideshow-wrapper?

Comment: Sure, you can use jquery and easily find the offset, though at the end of the day, you should decide if the texture effect is really worth all this trouble.

Comment: can you try adding transparent at end of background css beside repeat.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The transparent at end of background didn't work. I might look into the event listener. The images just look so good with the texture :-) so it's worth maybe giving it a shot. Cheers

Comment: check this if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

there r many solutions on this page.

Comment: Thanks Khurram for the link